# Creating a user in Ubuntu that can sudo (Dockerfile)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, sudo

Using Ubuntu 16 plus Docker, can I create a user "myuser" that can use `sudo` when necessary?

My Dockerfile looks roughly like:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN \
adduser --system --disabled-password myuser \
&& \
usermod -a -G sudo myuser

USER myuser
WORKDIR /home/myuser
```

I tried small variations on that, with e.g. `--ingroup sudo` in the `adduser` command.

However, I cannot get "myuser" to be able to run `sudo`. Instead I get `sudo: command not found` messages.

Answer (score 3):

`sudo` is not a binary which is included by default in modern ubuntu docker images (mostly because it's usually *unnecessary* to run `sudo` inside of docker)

In order to get a `sudo` binary you need to install it from `apt`

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends sudo
```